# Update column value after insert into table using trigger

Tags: mysql

I need to update ID column in table after Insert.
ID is varchar and auto-increment. I need to update the value of ID .
Eg.
when we insert a column and the ID value is supposed to be 10, so after the trigger is executed ID value should be updated to 10F.

Comment: Sounds like this is a *rendering* problem. Cant you just concatenate  “F” when using/presenting the ID?

Comment: That can not be done sir as the ID value is meant to differentiate between other ID values. I need to create a trigger so that when ever a new column in inserted the ID column gets updated and 'F' gets concatenated to it.

Comment: OK. Then it sounds like the ID isn’t really an ID, but is really part of a composite key. Fundamentally, IDs should never change, not even in a trigger at insert time. Triggers in general are a bad idea. Put the code in the app layer, where it’s easy to test and understand. Or add another column for the id_suffix and join/use the concatenation of ID and that column

Comment: Sir actually the scenario is that, there are 2 different tables that contains ID column, now we  have a query that gets me data from both the tables (using union). Now this ID column is used to know from which table the column data has come and accordingly i have to write code. I am not allowed to add new column to the table.

Comment: *ID is varchar and auto-increment.* Impossible, in MySQL the column with AUTO_INCREMENT may have only numeric datatype. *we insert a column and the ID value is supposed to be 10, so after the trigger is executed ID value should be updated to 10F.* Noway. Both trigger and generated column cannot use AUTO_INCREMENT column value. Simply generate this number in retrieving query.

Comment: *actually the scenario is that, there are 2 different tables that contains ID column, now we have a query that gets me data from both the tables (using union). Now this ID column is used to know from which table the column data has come and accordingly i have to write code.* Do this in your UNION code: `SELECT *, '1' source FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT *, 2 FROM table2`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you do not need to modify the ID column permanently, which you should never do anyway, but only during certain queries.

To use the ID to distinguish which table a row came from in a join s also a bag idea - IDs should not have any information “encoded” in them: They should be meaningless unique values.

If your design is broken and you absolutely must modify the ID:

```
select concat(id, 'F') as ID, other_columns from tableA
union all
select ID, other_columns from tableB
```

or better, introduce an extra column that indicates which table each row came from:

```
select *, 'F' as origin from tableA
union all
select *, '' as origin from tableB
```